# Trouble with an if/else statement which only returns final condition

Tags: javascript, if-statement, debugging

I'm attempting to debug a .js file I have. The file uses an if/then to return variables. Each variable is set to one `location.replace("url")`, so there should be one url returned at any given point.

I tried replacing each variable's `location.replace` with `console.log`, hoping that it'd simply return one result as the function is intended. Instead, it returned every single variable at once and just logged their underlying URLs.

Here's a short JSfiddle for the tidbit below: https://jsfiddle.net/j_Sani/ehutcnmb/12/

Here's a longer JSfiddle with more thorough variables:
https://jsfiddle.net/j_Sani/ehutcnmb/33/

```
<head>
<script>
var t1 = location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/");
var t2 = location.replace("https://www.google.com/");
var t3 = location.replace("https://www.bing.com/");

const now = new Date();
  const s1 = now.getHours() === 15;
  const s2 = now.getHours() === 16;

function go2() {
    if (s1) {
        return t1;
    } else if (s2) {
        return t2;
    } else {
        return t3;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Essentially right now, when I load the document in my browser, it reroutes to the final `else` by returning `t3`. I'd like it if I got any of the other variables in the statement. In my JSfiddle I've included a lengthier version with more `else if`'s.

All input is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you need to check with ``if(s1)`` and ``if(s2)``? These conditions are essentially checking they return ``true`` which will be false in this case and therefore ``t3`` will be returned.

Comment: You never even call `go2()` so issue has nothing to do with `if/else`. Your issue is in calling `location.replace()` which is immediate (and has no `return`)

Comment: Please don’t link to Fiddles, just include your code right here as a code snippet in your question

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger to check what `now.getHours()` returns? Do you need the === operator which compares value and type? You know that `now.getHours()` returns an integer by definition. Have you checked the values of s1 and s2? Could you not simplify the code by making one initial call to now.getHours() . `int hour = now.getHours();` and each of your if test can be `if (hour == n)` where n runs from 0 to 23.

Comment: Note that `now.getHours()` [returns an integer between 0 and 23](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/object-property-method/date-getHours.php) not 1 to 24 as in your longer code example.

Comment: Rohit, the extended JSfiddle included variables for other times of day. Thanks anyway. 

charlietfl, I called it in practice. The example is not as thorough as it should've been.

Scott, I didn't know. I've seen it in other threads and just thought it was an accepted practice. My apologies.

pjaj, thanks for the suggestion!

In hindsight, I suppose I should've been clearer. Sorry for the issues. My if/then and now.getHours work in my test environment with other variables and I botched the replication process for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Written this way, the `location` function is executed **immediately**.

```
var t3 = location.replace("https://www.bing.com/");
```

You need to put that statement inside your `if` statements.

Comment: Christopher, this worked. Thanks for the clarification!